# searching a list for multiple substrings in python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I have a list containing 10-15 links, and I want to search for the links that contain either 'sen_floor' or 'asm_floor'

this is my code so far (ca_data is the original link):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

ca = requests.get(ca_data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(ca.content, 'html.parser')
links = []

for link in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^http://")}):
   links.append(link.get('href'))

r = re.compile(".*vote")
newlist = list(filter(r.match, links))
print(newlist)

subs = 'sen_floor'
sen_votes = list(filter(lambda x: subs in x, newlist))
print(str(sen_votes))
```

this effectively returns a list of all links containing `sen_floor`. Ideally I'd like to have a separate list with `asm_floor`. I tried repeating the last paragraph:

```
sub = 'asm_floor'
asm_votes = list(filter(lambda x: sub in x, newlist))
print(str(asm_votes))
```

but it doesn't work, just returns the same result as the sen_floor search.

Help?

Comment: post the original list.

Comment: maybe first check manually in HTML if there are links with asm_floor and if they starts with `http://` - maybe there are relative links without `http://`

Comment: better put read ulr so we could run it, see problem, and test ideas/solutions

Comment: Here's the url that I've labelled ca_data: http://www.legislature.ca.gov/cgi-bin/port-postquery?bill_number=ab_2&sess=CUR&house=B&author=alejo_%3Calejo%3E

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(
    "http://www.legislature.ca.gov/cgi-bin/port-postquery?bill_number=ab_2&sess=CUR&house=B&author=alejo_%3Calejo%3E")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

sen = []
asm = []
for item in soup.findAll("a", {'href': True}):
    item = item.get("href")
    if 'sen_floor' in item:
        sen.append(item)
    elif 'asm_floor' in item:
        asm.append(item)
```

Comment: This is really, really close, and a lot more concise. All I have to do now is amend that the link also needs to contain 'vote', or i'm going to get a lot of amendment links I don't need. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just use contains operator with Or syntax to specify multiple substrings to match on in hrefs. This returns only hrefs containing either of the specified substrings. Use in a loop if checking multiple pages ensuring you update soup object.

```
matches = [i['href'] for i in soup.select('[href*=asm_floor],[href*=sen_floor]')]
```

Separate lists to add to

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.legislature.ca.gov/cgi-bin/port-postquery?bill_number=ab_2&sess=CUR&house=B&author=alejo_%3Calejo%3E")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
sen = [i['href'] for i in soup.select('[href*=sen_floor]')]
asm = [i['href'] for i in soup.select('[href*=asm_floor]')]
print('sen: ', sen)
print('asm:', asm)
```